# HttpPut and HttpDelete does not get called ASP.NET WebAPI deployed at local IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-web-api2, postman, http-put

Unable to call HttpPut and HttpDelete method from POSTMan Client to ASP.NET WebAPI 
below is the code along with web.config entry . I am running the WEBAPI on my local IIS. The HttpPost and HttpGet methods work.

[image]

On running the code from POSTMan client throws 404 error.
[image]

[image]

Web.Config values
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calling your PUT method is wrong.

Change the prototype of your method to:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("update/{cKey}"]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int cKey)
```

After that, your call in Postman should work.

The way you defined your route is not correct because the `cKey` variable never gets mapped. 
Since your method accepts a not nullable integer, you must supply it in your query string. So a request to `update?valQuestionPayload=123` will also work.

Comment: it is unchecked and does not work still unable to call the put methods